# A word that describe the art of using observable words to describe nonphysical/incorporeal thoughts and ideas

Tags: word-request

I want to know what is the structure art word of connection the visible expressions with abstract ideas and words?

What do we call this kind of structure?

For instance,

> - my friend’s answers were exposed to suspicion

Here we use expose in something abstract rather than saying

“His injuries were exposed to bacteria”

Here in this sense we can see something visible rather than invisible

I want to know what is the word that can describe the case when we use visible actions to describe the invisible actions!

Comment: Are you asking about the verb **expose** (and others like it) and how they work with things that actually exist and can be seen (e.g. bacteria, sunlight, rain) as well as intangible things (e.g. suspicion, ridicule)? Do you have verbs of Latin origin in mind, or any verb?

Comment: Yes, you understood my point. I want to know to what extent or is it always possible to use all the tangible words with abstract and intangible ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Possible choices:
abstract ideas
figurative
non-literal
metaphorical
allegorical

Not quite as good, however related ideas:
descriptive
denotative
illustrative
representative

Answer (score 0):

When the verb  is formed from pieces, as verbs from Latin often are, the original meaning is concrete and yet very basic, so that it is amenable to a variety of analogical figurative (non-concrete) meanings. Compare **expose**:

*ex* = out, outside, out in the open
*pose* = to put, to place, to set

It means to set something out in the open.

When out in the open, things are visible for all to see.  So we get the transitive meaning "to reveal".

When out in the open, things have no protection. So we get the transitive meaning "to make vulnerable" and the adjectival meaning "unprotected" of the past participle "exposed". But things are also freed of that which they had been beneath or behind, so we get the meaning "to give something access to something".

> The newspaper reporter exposed the politician's nefarious practices.
>
> If you remove the bandage, you will expose the cut to bacteria.
>
> You should remove the old bandage and expose the cut to sunlight.
>
> The soldiers moved out into the clearing where they felt exposed.

This process is not limited to verbs of Latin origin, of course.